# How to dispatch OnChange value ? e is not defined error React/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm building a filter component based on a movie list. I'm almost there. I've set up my action, reducer and components. Looking at my React/redux dev tools everything seems to be ok. however I can't dispatch my action properly.

Here is my component event :

```
<div>
  Year:
  <select
    defaultValue={selectedYear}
    onChange={e => onChangeYear(e.target.value)}
  >
    <option value="all" >All</option>
    {years.map((y, i) =>
      <option key={i} value={y}>{y}</option>
    )}
  </select>
</div>
```

and here is my dispatcher :

```
const mapDispachToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
  onChangeYear: () => {dispatch (onYearChange(e.target.value));
        },
    };
};
```

`onYearChange` is well imported and well defined in my action components.
how can I pass `e.target.value` in my dispatcher without any error ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your select's `onChange` attribute to just be set to `={onChangeYear}`, and in your dispatcher accept e as a parameter.

```
const mapDispachToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onChangeYear: () => {dispatch (onYearChange(e.target.value));
    },
};
```

becomes

```
const mapDispachToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onChangeYear: (e) => {dispatch (onYearChange(e.target.value));
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not following you on `in your dispatcher accept e as a parameter.` ?

Comment: I updated my answer to show where you were missing the parameter

Comment: Ok. I tried some stuff like but not this one :) So why do people are using `onChange={e => onChangeYear(e.target.value)}` at level component ?

Comment: Basically the difference between setting your event handler to `={onChangeYear}` and `={e => onChangeYear(e.target.value)}` is the first one calls onChangeYear and like all event handlers calls it with the event as the first parameter, while in your latter example you are defining an anonymous function (with the arrow function syntax) which calls onChangeYear and passes only the value from the event's target. Some people use anonymous functions in their event handlers to pass additional information that can't be extracted from the event, but you don't need to since you only access the event.

Comment: I would add that it is ill-advised to use arrow functions/anonymous functions in your render method, since render is called many times and that results in creating new functions on each render. This is inefficient as the old ones need to be cleaned up by garbage collection and can lead to performance stutters as a result.

Comment: Ok John. Thanks a lot. Can move on the next step.